# Is string.ToCharArray() necessary for enumerating?

Tags: c#, enumeration, securestring

Why on Earth would someone convert a string to a char[] before enumerating the characters in it? The regular pattern for initializing a System.Security.SecureString found all around the net follows:

```
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "fizzbuzz".ToCharArray())
{
    secureString.AppendChar(c);
}
```

Calling ToCharArray() makes no sense for me. Could someone tell whether I am wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, it's not necessary in this context. The only time you need `ToCharArray` is when you *actually* need an array.

My guess is that most people who call `ToCharArray` don't know that `string` implements `IEnumerable` (even though as far as I know it always has).

Comment: Thanks. Reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420122/using-securestring and http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/8a3b075c-d74d-43ee-8937-1136289751de.aspx and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winserverpowershell/thread/4df7c4e6-bd5e-46b5-9a74-ac7c3d8c7314 I was really confused about why nobody left out this ToCharArray call.

Comment: A lot of it may be cargo cult programming. People see others do it and not ever investigate to understand why it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that is bad because it

- enumerates on the string
- creates an array with a copy of all chars
- enumerates on that

A lot of unnecessary work...

That's because strings are immutable, and giving out a pointer to its internal array is not allowed, so ToCharArray() makes a copy instead of a cast.

That is:

you can enumerate a string as a char[] but:

you cannot:

```
var chars = (char[])"string";
```

If you would go enumerating and would want to break at some point, by using the toCharArray() would already have enumerated the whole string nad made a copy of all chars. If the string would be very big, that is quite expensive...