# How can I use ConvertTo-SecureString

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, encryption, aes

Let's say I need to do this in Powershell:

```
    $SecurePass = Get-Content $CredPath | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
    [String]$CleartextPass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($CredPass));
```

The content of $CredPath is a file that contains the output of ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key (1..16).

How do I accomplish the `ConvertTo-SecureString -key (1..16)` portion in C#/.NET?

I know how to create a `SecureString`, but I'm not sure how the encryption should be handled.

Do I encrypt each character using AES, or decrypt the string and then create a the secure string per character?

I know next to nothing about cryptography, but from what I've gathered I might just want to invoke the Powershell command using C#.

For reference, I found a similar post about AES encryption/decryption here:
[Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)

UPDATE

[I have reviewed the link Keith posted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aes.aspx), but I face additional unknowns. The DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes takes three arguments:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
```

The first argument is a byte array represents the encrypted text. The question here is, how should the string be represented in the byte array? Should it be represented with or without encoding?

```
byte[] ciphertext = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encrypted_text);
byte[] ciphertext = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encrypted_text);
byte[] ciphertext = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encrypted_text);    

byte[] ciphertext = new byte[encrypted_password.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted_password.ToCharArray(), 0, text, 0, text.Length);
```

The second byte array is the key should simply be an array of integers:

```
byte[] key = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 };
```

The third byte array is an "Initialization Vector" - it looks like the Aes.Create() call will generate a byte[] for IV randomly. Reading around, I've found that I might need to use the same IV. As ConvertFrom-SecureString and ConvertTo-SecureString are able to encrypt/decrypt using simply the key, I am left with the assumption that the IV[] can be random -or- has a static definition.

I have not yet found a winning combination, but I will keep trying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to SecureString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570422/convert-string-to-securestring)

Comment: One of the other PowerShell MVPs believes the string is Base64 encoded.  It appears that there are three sets of data delimited by the `|` char. The middle set may be the IV data.

Comment: Hmm, (s)he might be right. If one of the three is an IV and one represents the encrypted text, what would the third delimited item be? Perhaps a salt for the supplied key?

Comment: For the same problem, but in the case where a key is not provided (i.e. where ConvertFrom-SecureString has been used without a key), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880731/securely-convert-encrypted-standard-string-to-securestring.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is an old post.  I am posting this for completeness and posterity, because I couldn't find a complete answer on MSDN or stackoverflow.  It will be here in case I ever need to do this again.

It is a C# implementation of of powershell's ConvertTo-SecureString with AES encryption (turned on by using the -key option).  I will leave it for exercise to code a C# implementation of ConvertFrom-SecureString.

```
# forward direction
[securestring] $someSecureString = read-host -assecurestring
[string] $psProtectedString = ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (1..16) -SecureString $someSecureString
# reverse direction
$back = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $psProtectedString -key (1..16)
```

My work is combining answers and re-arranging user2748365's answer to be more readable and adding educational comments!  I also fixed the issue with taking a substring -- at the time of this post, his code only has two elements in strArray.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Globalization;

// psProtectedString - this is the output from
//   powershell> $psProtectedString = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $aSecureString -key (1..16)
// key - make sure you add size checking 
// notes: this will throw an cryptographic invalid padding exception if it cannot decrypt correctly (wrong key)
public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string psProtectedString, byte[] key)
{
    // '|' is indeed the separater
    byte[] asBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( psProtectedString );
    string[] strArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(asBytes).Split(new[] { '|' });

    if (strArray.Length != 3) throw new InvalidDataException("input had incorrect format");

    // strArray[0] is a static/magic header or signature (different passwords produce
    //    the same header)  It unused in our case, looks like 16 bytes as hex-string
    // you know strArray[1] is a base64 string by the '=' at the end
    //    the IV is shorter than the body, and you can verify that it is the IV, 
    //    because it is exactly 16bytes=128bits and it decrypts the password correctly
    // you know strArray[2] is a hex-string because it is [0-9a-f]
    byte[] magicHeader = HexStringToByteArray(encrypted.Substring(0, 32));
    byte[] rgbIV = Convert.FromBase64String(strArray[1]);
    byte[] cipherBytes = HexStringToByteArray(strArray[2]);

    // setup the decrypter
    SecureString str = new SecureString();
    SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
    ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, rgbIV);
    using (var stream = new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(cipherBytes), transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        // using this silly loop format to loop one char at a time
        // so we never store the entire password naked in memory
        int numRed = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2]; // two bytes per unicode char
        while( (numRed = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 )
        {
            str.AppendChar(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer).ToCharArray()[0]);
        }
    }

    //
    // non-production code
    // recover the SecureString; just to check
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818704/how-to-convert-securestring-to-system-string
    //
    IntPtr valuePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    string secureStringValue = "";
    try
    {
        // get the string back
        valuePtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(str);
        secureStringValue = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(valuePtr);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(valuePtr);
    }

    return str;
}
// from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2) bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);

    return bytes;
}
public static SecureString DecryptPassword( string psPasswordFile, byte[] key )
{
    if( ! File.Exists(psPasswordFile)) throw new ArgumentException("file does not exist: " + psPasswordFile);

    string formattedCipherText = File.ReadAllText( psPasswordFile );

    return ConvertToSecureString(formattedCipherText, key);
}
```

Comment: ConvertToSecureString(password, new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}); was what i was missing

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs on ConvertFrom-SecureString the AES encryption algorithm is used:

> If an encryption key is specified by using the Key or SecureKey
>   parameters, the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption
>   algorithm is used. The specified key must have a length of 128, 192,
>   or 256 bits because those are the key lengths supported by the AES
>   encryption algorithm. If no key is specified, the Windows Data
>   Protection API (DPAPI) is used to encrypt the standard string
>   representation.

Look at the DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes example in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aes.aspx).

BTW an easy option would be to use the PowerShell engine from C# to execute the `ConvertTo-SecureString` cmdlet to do the work.  Otherwise, it looks like the initialization vector is embedded somewhere in the ConvertFrom-SecureString output and may or may not be easy to extract.

Comment: I did find that page earlier, but I still face an unknown. The DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes takes three arguments:

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question with additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Cheng's answer - I found I had to change:

```
byte[] magicHeader = HexStringToByteArray(encrypted.Substring(0, 32));
```

to

```
byte[] magicHeader = HexStringToByteArray(psProtectedString.Substring(0, 32));
```

and

```
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
```

to

```
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = Aes.Create();
```

but it otherwise works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I accomplish the ConvertTo-SecureString -key (1..16) portion in C#/.NET?

Please see the following code:

```
    private static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string encrypted, string header, byte[] key)
    {
        string[] strArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted.Substring(header.Length, encrypted.Length - header.Length))).Split(new[] {'|'});
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
        int num2 = strArray[2].Length/2;
        var bytes = new byte[num2];
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++)
            bytes[i] = byte.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(2*i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, Convert.FromBase64String(strArray[1]));
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(new MemoryStream(bytes), transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bytes.Length];
            int num = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var data = new byte[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) data[i] = buffer[i];
            var str = new SecureString();
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length/2; j++) str.AppendChar((char) ((data[(2*j) + 1]*0x100) + data[2*j]));
            return str;
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
    encrypted = "76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8ADcAbgBiAGoAVQBCAFIANABNADgAYwBSAEoAQQA1AGQAZgAvAHYAYwAvAHcAPQA9AHwAZAAzADQAYwBhADYAOQAxAGIAZgA2ADgAZgA0AGMANwBjADQAYwBiADkAZgA1ADgAZgBiAGQAMwA3AGQAZgAzAA==";
    header = "76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345";
```

If you want to get decrypted characters, please check **data** in the method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest and simplest way was to call the `ConvertTo-SecureString` PowerShell command directly from C#. That way there's no difference in the implementation and the output is exactly what it would be if you called it from PowerShell directly.

```
    string encryptedPassword = RunPowerShellCommand("\"" 
            + password 
            + "\" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString", null);

    public static string RunPowerShellCommand(string command, 
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // Set up the running of the script
            powerShellInstance.AddScript(command);

            // Add the parameters
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    powerShellInstance.AddParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
                }
            }

            // Run the command
            Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var errorMessage in powerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
                {
                    if (errorMessage != null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var outputLine in psOutput)
            {
                if (outputLine != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(outputLine);
                }
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
```