# Decrypt SecureString with custom key

Tags: c#, powershell, encryption, symmetric-key

Actually i'm decrypting strings that i've created with powershell in c#.

I create the SecureString with following Powershell command:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString -String "TopSecret" -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

I decrypt the SecureString with following C# code:

```
        string exportedData = string.Empty;
        bool SecureStringOK = true;

        try
        {
            // Read args[0] to string
            exportedData = args[0];
        }
        catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NO_SECURESTRING");
            Debug.WriteLine("NO_SECURESTRING");
            SecureStringOK = false;
        }

        if (SecureStringOK)
        {

            // Decrypt the byte array to Unicode byte array
            try
            {
                // Remove all new-lines
                exportedData = exportedData.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");

                // Convert the hex dump to byte array
                int length = exportedData.Length / 2;
                byte[] encryptedData = new byte[length];
                for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
                {
                    encryptedData[index] = byte.Parse(exportedData.Substring(2 * index, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }

                byte[] data = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, (byte[])null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

                // Convert Unicode byte array to string
                string password = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);

                // Write Output
                Console.WriteLine(password);
                Debug.WriteLine(password);
            }
            catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WRONG_SECURESTRING: " + args[0]);
                Debug.WriteLine("WRONG_SECURESTRING: " + args[0]);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WRONG_SECURESTRING_FORMAT: " + args[0]);
                Debug.WriteLine("WRONG_SECURESTRING_FORMAT: " + args[0]);
            }

        }
```

This works fine in both direction, but now i create the SecureString in Powershell with my own key file:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString -String "TopSecret" -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $KeyPath
```

Any ideas what i've to change in the c# code to use a specific key file?

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a key, PowerShell encrypts using the `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes`-class instead of `ProtectedData`, so you need to quite a few changes.

> If an encryption key is specified by using the Key or SecureKey
>   parameters, the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption
>   algorithm is used. The specified key must have a length of 128, 192,
>   or 256 bits, because those are the key lengths supported by the AES
>   encryption algorithm. If no key is specified, the Windows Data
>   Protection API (DPAPI) is used to encrypt the standard string
>   representation.

[ConvertFrom-SecureString @ TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849814.aspx)

Personally, I would use the `ConvertTo-SecureString`-cmdlet in C# to avoid reinventing the wheel.

See [Aes Constructor @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aes.aspx) and this [previous SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633826/how-can-i-use-convertto-securestring) for C#-solution.